# Python 3.6 HTTP Server not reachable when compiled by PyInstaller on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pyinstaller, httpserver

I created a web server in Python 3.6 using `http.server.HTTPServer`, `http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` and `socketserver.ThreadingMixIn`. It works as expected and I can access the webpage from any device on the local network.

I compiled it with `PyInstaller` to create a Windows executable. The webpage works with localhost, but it is not accessible from any device on the local network.

I used `nmap` from another device to scan the computer hosting the web server, and it appears that the port used by the webserver (`8080`) is open when I run my script normally (with the Python interpreter), and everything works. However, when I use the executable produced by `PyInstaller` the port isn't open and the webpage not reachable.

The executable doesn't produce any errors, and apart from that everything works.
I have tried to run the .exe file as administrator, and to this disable my antivirus/firewall. It doesn't work.

Here is my `PyInstaller` command : 
`pyinstaller --runtime-tmpdir "" --onefile -i icon.ico script.py`

And here is the relevant code in my python file :

```
import http.server  
import socketserver

port = 8080

class ThreadingSimpleServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, http.server.HTTPServer):
    pass #using this so the webserver can handle mutliple requests at a time

class myWebServer(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_POST(self):
        #does stuff

try:
   server = ThreadingSimpleServer(('', port), myWebServer)
   server.serve_forever()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('^C received, shutting down the program.')
    server.socket.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I run your code and it works for me. The O.S. ask about opening the connection and everything seems to be ok. You must produce a log of some kind in order to let us understand what is going wrong. In my run i omit the -i switch because I don't have a .ico file.

Comment: I solved the problem, but I still don't fully understand what caused it. See my answer. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I solved the issue but I still don't understand what caused it. Since the beginning I was building my script in a folder located in AppData : it wasn't working and I had no Windows firewall warning/confirmation showing up.

I moved my script to the Desktop and compiled it here : the Windows firewall confirmation showed up ([this one](https://winaero.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Windows-10-Firewall-Notifications.png)) and the executable worked well.

I thought maybe the firewall might have flagged my program earlier and all the subsequent builds were blacklisted or something like that so I tried to compile the script in the original location, but this time I renamed it and I deleted all the files generated previously : it didn't work either (and no firewall confirmation/warning).

So now i'm pretty sure the error was caused by the firewall, and it had to do with the location from where the build was done, but I don't really understand why.

Comment: The appdata folder can be tricky. Never build/develop in a non standard folder. Eg use Documents, Desktop.